# Blender Animations glitchy in Unity

Tags: unity, animation, blender, fbx

I have created a gorilla and its animations in Blender, exported the file as an FBX file and then imported it in Unity. The animations works fine in Blender, the loop is perfect for the walking animation. When I play the animations in Unity (in the animation preview and in game) it glitches at the moment where it loops, the arms make a really strange quick move. Is there anything special to do to export Blender animations ? Tell me if you need more informations.

Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb58svuig6ovwhs/Gorilla_Animations.blend?dl=0) to my blender file, if you want to try exporting it and import it in Unity.

Comment: You might want to check the import settings of the model inside Unity. View the model in the inspector, go to the Rig tab and try changing the animation type?

Comment: When importing from blender, you should: 1)set the animation type from legacy, to humanoid. 2)set up the gorilla's avatar by clicking on it on click on configure avatar. Now check if all the animations, walk, run, jump cycles are present in the "import animations tab".

Comment: @GabrieleVierti that looks like an answer to me. If you'd care to elaborate on the steps, you could claim the bounty on this question. ;)

Comment: @DMGregory uuuh that's true! thanks for the tip ahah ;)

Answer (score 1):

***IMPORTING 3D MODELS WITH ANIMATIONS FROM BLENDER***

[First of all, you import the 3d model, by dragging it into your project]

1) Select the gorilla

2) go under the ***rig*** tab and set ***animation type*** from ***legacy*** to ***humanoid***

[image]

3) Unity by default doesn't know by default how you created your model, it can only make assumptions on how your gorilla's skeleton is configured. Beacuse of this we need to click on ***avatar definition*** and ***create from this model***

[image]

4)Once you configured your model's skeleton(it's pretty intuitive, you just have to click on a spot on the skeleton image and assign the corresponding bone transform to it), you should also check in the ***Animations*** tab if there are all the animation cycles you created for the gorilla. Sometimes you also have to specify the keyframes an animation starts and ends, but most of the times it should be all fine by default.

[image: This image shows how you can specify the start and end frames of an animations]

5)If you have done everything correctly, you should have the gorilla, with it's own configured avatar and animations ;)